# vba check value in column then check month and year of date in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

i am searching for a value in my column A on sheet 2. the below code works fine, and if the value is found it shows the message found else it shows not found if the value is not found.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Range("B1").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "found" 'value not found
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
            End If
        End With
    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

what i want to do is add to this code so that as well as searching column A for one value also search Column B for a different value? and then if both values exist say found else say not found.

would someone please be able to show me how i can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep with your flow, perhaps add another Find:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "col A value found"
                FindString = "<different find string>"
                With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B") 'searches all of column B
                Set Rng = .Find(What:="<different find string>", _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "both values found" 'value found
                    Else
                        MsgBox "col B values not found" 'value not found
                    End If
            Else
                MsgBox "col A value not found" 'value not found
            End If
        End With
```